# Solaris 10 local zone change time

Tags: solaris

I need to change the time for one of the local zone. I have encounter error, date: Not owner when I tried to do using the date command. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Good evening MFAY,
The non-global zone takes the date and time from the global zone and that is something that can be change setting the sys_time privilege. This setting must be handle with enormous precaution because it can/will affect the rest of the zones including the global one.
See the following doc to get a better idea:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54752/gpscx.html

Comment: That's true for Solaris 10 through 11.2.  Solaris 11.3 introduced the ability to [set different time in different zones](https://blogs.oracle.com/anuthan/entry/different_time_in_different_zones) as documented under [Setting Time Values in Non-Global Oracle Solaris Zones](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54752/gpscx.html).